# how to to loose couple html and javascript

Tags: javascript

How to to loose couple html and javascript... Is it necessary, worth ?
You have to always use some html elements inside javascript logic...
I know from c# you can lose couple for maintenance and test scenarios.

Comment: Search for ["javascript templates"](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascirpt+emplates&oq=javascirpt+emplates&aqs=chrome.0.57.4088&sugexp=chrome,mod=17&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&spell=1&q=javascript+templates&sa=X&ei=PIrbUKaBIIvc8AT4vYDQDw&ved=0CDQQvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.eWU&fp=b120f3e780b613e5&bpcl=40096503&biw=1652&bih=892).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate them pretty easily; just keep the majority of the JavaScript separate from the JavaScript that interacts with the DOM, using functions and the like. Kinda like views and controllers.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best frameworks for separating the DOM and your javascript is Knockout.JS.

I find it incredibly smart with the separation of concerns. The view model can be completely unit testable.